# CodeIgniter: pagination doesn't have question mark?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

The code below generates pagination using query strings. However, there is no leading `?`. So, I get something like this: `http://localhost/index.php/search/&limit=10`. **Any ideas why?**

```
this->load->library('pagination');

$config                   = array();
$config['base_url']       = 'http://localhost/index.php/search/';
$config['total_rows']     = 200;
$config['per_page']       = 10;
$config['num_links']      = 4;

$config['full_tag_open']  = '<ol>';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ol>';

$config['first_link']      = 'First';
$config['first_tag_open']  = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['last_link']      = 'Last';
$config['last_tag_open']  = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['next_link']      = 'Next';
$config['next_tag_open']  = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['prev_link']      = 'Previous';
$config['prev_tag_open']  = '<li>';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['cur_tag_open']  = '<li class="active">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['num_tag_open']  = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
echo ($this->pagination->create_links());
```

**EDIT 1:**

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/161263/

**EDIT 2:**

The docs seem to suggest that what I did should work: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

`$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;`

By default, the pagination library assume you are using URI Segments, and constructs your links something like

`http://example.com/index.php/test/page/20`

If you have `$config['enable_query_strings']` set to TRUE your links will automatically be re-written using Query Strings. This option can also be explictly set. Using `$config['page_query_string']` set to `TRUE`, the pagination link will become.

`http://example.com/index.php?c=test&m=page&per_page=20`

Comment: OK, that worked. Why do I need to set this? I'm not using URI segments. Also, now I have something like this: `http://localhost/index.php/search/?&limit=10` -- the `&` can be ignored safely, right?

Comment: Because the stupid uri_segment is default to three ... can ignored safely.

Comment: Is the query string considered the 2nd URI segment?

Comment: i don't have the answer, need to check the code itself. if act like i will put /&limit=20 for after url_segment 2, if the page only have two segment, then is /?&. if not by mistake, once you going to page 2, the link probably will broken again

Comment: One more thing, how do I make another page number that active one? Right now, page 1 is the active one. What if I were on page 2? How do I make that page active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this myself.  When using query strings, CodeIgniter has to assume you have other query string parameters (BUT, CI assumes you're using query string parameters to map your controller and method...).  I like using query string for stuff like filtering results and such, while still using the basic routing options in the URI (like you).

I've had to live with the ?& personally, but I suppose you could extend the Pagination library like so (long function, sorry):

```
class MY_Pagination extends CI_Pagination {
function create_links()
{
    // If our item count or per-page total is zero there is no need to continue.
    if ($this->total_rows == 0 OR $this->per_page == 0)
    {
        return '';
    }

    // Calculate the total number of pages
    $num_pages = ceil($this->total_rows / $this->per_page);

    // Is there only one page? Hm... nothing more to do here then.
    if ($num_pages == 1)
    {
        return '';
    }

    // Determine the current page number.
    $CI =& get_instance();

    if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
    {
        if ($CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment) != 0)
        {
            $this->cur_page = $CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment);

            // Prep the current page - no funny business!
            $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment) != 0)
        {
            $this->cur_page = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);

            // Prep the current page - no funny business!
            $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
        }
    }

    $this->num_links = (int)$this->num_links;

    if ($this->num_links < 1)
    {
        show_error('Your number of links must be a positive number.');
    }

    if ( ! is_numeric($this->cur_page))
    {
        $this->cur_page = 0;
    }

    // Is the page number beyond the result range?
    // If so we show the last page
    if ($this->cur_page > $this->total_rows)
    {
        $this->cur_page = ($num_pages - 1) * $this->per_page;
    }

    $uri_page_number = $this->cur_page;
    $this->cur_page = floor(($this->cur_page/$this->per_page) + 1);

    // Calculate the start and end numbers. These determine
    // which number to start and end the digit links with
    $start = (($this->cur_page - $this->num_links) > 0) ? $this->cur_page - ($this->num_links - 1) : 1;
    $end   = (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages) ? $this->cur_page + $this->num_links : $num_pages;

    // Is pagination being used over GET or POST?  If get, add a per_page query
    // string. If post, add a trailing slash to the base URL if needed
    if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
    {
        $this->base_url = str_replace('?&amp;', '?', rtrim($this->base_url).'&amp;'.$this->query_string_segment.'=');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url, '/') .'/';
    }

    // And here we go...
    $output = '';

    // Render the "First" link
    if  ($this->first_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page > ($this->num_links + 1))
    {
        $first_url = ($this->first_url == '') ? $this->base_url : $this->first_url;
        $output .= $this->first_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$first_url.'">'.$this->first_link.'</a>'.$this->first_tag_close;
    }

    // Render the "previous" link
    if  ($this->prev_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page != 1)
    {
        $i = $uri_page_number - $this->per_page;

        if ($i == 0 && $this->first_url != '')
        {
            $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->first_url.'">'.$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
        }
        else
        {
            $i = ($i == 0) ? '' : $this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix;
            $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$i.'">'.$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
        }

    }

    // Render the pages
    if ($this->display_pages !== FALSE)
    {
        // Write the digit links
        for ($loop = $start -1; $loop <= $end; $loop++)
        {
            $i = ($loop * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;

            if ($i >= 0)
            {
                if ($this->cur_page == $loop)
                {
                    $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$loop.$this->cur_tag_close; // Current page
                }
                else
                {
                    $n = ($i == 0) ? '' : $i;

                    if ($n == '' && $this->first_url != '')
                    {
                        $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->first_url.'">'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $n = ($n == '') ? '' : $this->prefix.$n.$this->suffix;

                        $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$n.'">'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Render the "next" link
    if ($this->next_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page < $num_pages)
    {
        $output .= $this->next_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$this->prefix.($this->cur_page * $this->per_page).$this->suffix.'">'.$this->next_link.'</a>'.$this->next_tag_close;
    }

    // Render the "Last" link
    if ($this->last_link !== FALSE AND ($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages)
    {
        $i = (($num_pages * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page);
        $output .= $this->last_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix.'">'.$this->last_link.'</a>'.$this->last_tag_close;
    }

    // Kill double slashes.  Note: Sometimes we can end up with a double slash
    // in the penultimate link so we'll kill all double slashes.
    $output = preg_replace("#([^:])//+#", "\\1/", $output);

    // Add the wrapper HTML if exists
    $output = $this->full_tag_open.$output.$this->full_tag_close;

    return $output;
}
}
```

Comment: >> (BUT, CI assumes you're using query string parameters to map your controller and method...) - can you please elaborate on this? I thought you can only map to controller and method using URI segments.

Comment: The "$config['enable_query_string']" directive was originally used to make your URLs map differently.  $_GET['c'] maps to the controller, and I forget the rest.  I've never seen someone use it that way, but the Pagination class still reflects that assumption.  It thinks it's a safe assumption that there's an existing query string (indicating the controller / action), and it's safe just to append the per_page value and move on.  Make sense?