# How can i use url parameters instead of sections for page number and per page values?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, url-parameters

My current product pagination links look like this:

```
http://ecommerce.site/products/category/sub-category/page/5/per_page/9
```

I would like to build them like this:

```
http://ecommerce.site/products/category/sub-category?page=5&per_page=9
```

So as to separate pagination from the URL and be able to tell search engines what to do with each parameter.

My current pagination config is this:

```
$config['per_page'] = $per_page;
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'/products/'.$data['category']->slug.'/'.$data['sub-category']->slug.'/';
$config['prefix'] = 'page/';
$config['suffix'] = ($per_page != 9 ? '/per_page/'.$per_page : '').'?'.http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");
$config['uri_segment'] = '4';
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['num_links'] = '3';
$config['prev_link'] = '&#8249;';
$config['next_link'] = '&#8250;';
$config['first_link'] = '&laquo;';
$config['last_link'] = '&raquo;';
$config['total_rows'] = $data['products_total'];
```

**Edit**

kumal_v suggested to use the `page_query_string` parameter which I had missed in [CodeIgniter's pagination documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html), I've answered the question with my current config.

Comment: did you enable query string in CI configuration ?

Comment: I understand [enabling query strings](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) would force me to use parameters for everything, I would need this only for the pagination library.

Comment: You can enable for pagination only. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing

Enabled query strings for pagination and changed the parameter that contains the page number (by default it is set to 'per_page')

```
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
```

Set the base URL for the pagination links

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'/products/'.$data['category']->slug.'/'.$data['sub-category']->slug;
```

I use additional parameters which I preserve in the pagination URLs, this is to avoid recursively including the *page* parameter. Also it will keep the parameters for the first_url which by default will have none.

```
$query_string = $_GET;
if (isset($query_string['page']))
{
    unset($query_string['page']);
}

if (count($query_string) > 0)
{
    $config['suffix'] = '&' . http_build_query($query_string, '', "&");
    $config['first_url'] = $config['base_url'] . '?' . http_build_query($query_string, '', "&");
}
```

Set the rest of the pagination config

```
$config['per_page'] = $per_page;        
$config['uri_segment'] = '4';
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['num_links'] = '3';
$config['prev_link'] = '&#8249;';
$config['next_link'] = '&#8250;';
$config['first_link'] = '&laquo;';
$config['last_link'] = '&raquo;';
$config['total_rows'] = $data['products_total'];
```

**Optional** Modify / extend the pagination library to use '?' instead of '&'.

Replace this line

```
$this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url).'&amp'.$this->query_string_segment.'=';
```

With this line

```
$this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url).'?'.$this->query_string_segment.'=';
```

This works in this case because I know 'page' will always be the first parameter as I'm not using `enable_query_strings`.

If you don't want to modify / extend the pagination library, you will have to add the '?' to the `$config['base_url']`. The pagination URLs will have both '?' and '&' like '?&page=6'.

**Sources**

[kumar_v's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21169035/1132838)

[CodeIgniters pagination documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html)

[Preserving GET URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384644/codeigniter-pagination-url-with-get-parameters)

[Getting pagination to use '?' instead of '&'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371739/codeigniter-pagination-doesnt-have-question-mark)

Comment: I'd also recommend setting pagination's `use_page_numbers` to true and calculate the offset for your queries via `$offset = isset ( $_GET['page'] ) ? ( $_GET['page'] - 1 ) * $per_page : 0;`

Answer (score 0):

First enable query string in pagination

```
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Then change pagination url sufix as:

```
$config['suffix'] = "?page=".$yourcurrent_page_no."&per_page=".$per_page;
```

Comment: The site was developed using CodeIgniter 1, I think that option is only available on CodeIgniter 2.

Comment: Even it's available in CI 2, You can do another one thing. let me update my answer/

Comment: That didn't work as expected, it produced `http://ecommerce.site/products/category/sub-category&per_page=3?page=4&per_page=9`

Comment: I think it's because of prefix. did you remove prefix and try?

Comment: Yes, I removed it. The thing is CI's pagination library will use the value of `query_string_segment` (by default 'per_page') as the parameter for the page value and will append it to the query string with an '&' it will also respectively prepend and append whatever you set on the `prefix` and `sufix` variables.

Comment: so, your problem fixed?

Comment: We are getting there :)